# problems with 'RV_INVOICE_DOCUMENT_READ'

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm trying to use the 'RV_INVOICE_DOCUMENT_READ' function to get some price data from a bill. Checking the function in the SE37 works fine, it retrieves the data I need. However, when I try to use the function in a smartform, the function returns nothing. This is the code I have:

```
DATA: LV_VBRK LIKE VBRK.
LV_VBRK-VBELN = VL_VBELN.

DATA:
gs_komv TYPE komv,
gt_komv like komv occurs 0 with header line,
gs_vbpa TYPE vbpavb,
gt_vbpa like vbpavb occurs 0 with header line,
gs_vbrk TYPE vbrkvb,
gt_vbrk like vbrkvb occurs 0 with header line,
gs_vbrp TYPE vbrpvb,
gt_vbrp like vbrpvb occurs 0 with header line.

CALL FUNCTION 'RV_INVOICE_DOCUMENT_READ'
 EXPORTING
   KONV_READ = 'X'
   VBRK_I = LV_VBRK
 TABLES
   xkomv = gt_komv
   xvbpa = gt_vbpa
   xvbrk = gt_vbrk
   xvbrp = gt_vbrp.
```

When I check gt_komv, it contains zero records, but when in the SE37 it returns 28 records. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does the `VL_VBELN` come from? The domain behind the field has alpha conversion set.

`SE37`, when calling FMs does input alpha conversion when processing parameters, so in ABAP you need internal format when passing to it.

More about alpha conversion [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/9b/f9c18f5a07f0459127e9676ae22a54/content.htm).